# Затухающая подсветка обновленного элемента в Listbox`е / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, listbox

Есть Listbox привязанный к коллекции, и отображающий одно поле из нее. При изменении в коллекции нужно сделать вспышку фона соответствующего элемента в списке.
Класс коллекции примерно:

```
public class Property : BindableBase 
{ 
  private string _fullName = ""; 
  public string Fullname 
  { 
    get => _fullName; 
    set 
    { 
      SetProperty(ref _fullname, value); 
      Update = true; 
      _update = false; 
    } 
  } 
  private bool _update = false; 
  public bool Update 
  { 
    get => _update;
    set => SetProperty(ref _update, value); 
  } 
  ...
}
```

И главное находил решение и делал раньше, сейчас ни найти ни вспомнить как не могу, вроде решал через DataTrigger, но чета нефига не хочет анимация срабатывать

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Update}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Green" Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" >
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname, Mode=OneWay}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Помогите с решение проблемки.

Comment: У вас в коде была опечатка - свойство называлось Upgate вместо Update. Я поправил код. Если вам правка видна, попробуйте у себя. Ну или просто переименуйте свойство

Comment: Кроме того, вызывать анимацию вот таким образом
 Update = true; 
      _update = false; 
очень плохое решение. Сделайте лучше триггер на установку Name в XAML, и уберите Update из кода в принципе.

Comment: спасиб за правку, но работать оно от это не начало (((

Comment: Можно подробнее про триггер на установку Name в XAML, ибо знал бы как не изобретал бы такой оборот? Я так понимаю это через EventTrigger, но какой RoutedEvent тогда будет?

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ, Binding умеет сообщать когда меняется цель привязки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не должны сочинять костыли для анимации внутри VM. Это чисто задача представления, на уровне представления ее и нужно решать, благо фреймворк предоставляет для этого средства, в частности, `Binding` умеет генерировать события при обновлении цели привязки, просто нужно их включить:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                From="Green" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хха, вот это фокус. Такого я ещё не пробовал. Спасибо! Взял на вооружение, добавил в свой пет проектик :)

Comment: Просто СУПЕР!!! 
Три дня мыслительных дум закончились ))) СПАСИБО!!!
Маленький нюанс, класс коллекции содержит множество полей, а отображаете только одно в списке, и именно его изменение вызывает эффект, на изменение остальных естественно реакции нет. Я всеж добавил поле текущего времени и в шаблон Textbox с нулевыми размерами для его отображения, и событие взял с него. Мож  посоветуете что-то правильнее, хотя меня и так это устраивает?

Comment: один вопросик только - можно ли это сделать не для обновленного, а для добавленного элемента? Или хотя бы игнорировать какие то проперти, что были обновлены?

Comment: @РубикЮрий, а вам надо реагировать и на изменения тех свойств, которые не отображаются? Если к ним нет привязки, то, естественно, некому вызывать `Binding.TargetUpdated`, в этом вся суть...

Comment: @tym32167, просто не включайте у тех привязок за которыми не нужно следить `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True`

Comment: Да у меня автосгенерированные колонки и поля, потому я включил для всей коллекции это.. Видимо, придется переопределять шаблон строчки, чтобы подсвечивалось.

Comment: @tym32167, другой вариант — запускать анимацию не декларативно, а в кодбихайнде, подписавшись на `Binding.TargetUpdated` и как-то фильтровать события там

Comment: Сделал обычным дата триггером, но за фокус спасибо :)