# Запустить анимацию при изменении свойства ViewModel

Tags: wpf, .net

Подскажите, можно ли определить анимацию элемента во View и при изменении некоторого свойства во ViewModel запустить ее. Грубо говоря может ли событие `OnPropertyChanged("Name")` запустить анимацию в каком либо из элементов?
У меня есть ToggleButton, который при переходе из состояния False в состояние True должен запустить анимацию для соседнего элемента. при этом сам он привязан к свойству во ViewModel: IsChecked="{Binding ToogleButtonIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"

**edit:**
переключатель ToogleButten меняет состояние модели. При смене состояния из false в true происходит смена текста через анимацию. Текст плавно меняет цвет, содержание, потом обновляется на тот, что дает ему ViewModel. Text1 --> *Wait...*(меняет цвет и содержание на время ) --> Text2

Comment: А при чем тут модель? В заголовке есть, а в теле что то про модель не слова. Ну да ладно... Триггером пробовали? Привяжите его к `ToogleButtonIsChecked`, либо вовсе к `ToggleButton`. Или я неверно вопрос понял?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, поправил заголовок. Так как на странице несколько таких пар кнопка-соседний_элемент, то для каждого элемента прописывать связь с каждой кнопкой через ее имя не хотелось бы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Затухающая подсветка обновленного элемента в Listbox\`е / WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835884/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-listbox%d0%b5-wpf)

Comment: Опишите более подробно вашу задачу. Что именно за анимация вам нужна, и что она должна показывать?

Comment: @VladD, обновил топик

Comment: @Mihail: У новый текст на деле доступен сразу, или только после паузы?

Comment: @VladD, да, текст уже известен, и его цвет тоже известен (там два варианта цвета), но пред сменой текста он должен пройти через промежуточный этап анимации. Во время анимации вместо него появляется сообщение что-то вроде "идет смена параметра, подождите..." в другой расцветке, которая плавно меняется

Comment: А нельзя это информационное сообщение просто поверх отображать отдельным контролом? Типа как здесь: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/BusyIndicator

Comment: @Mihail: Тогда почему бы не сделать как тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583262/10105? В том ответе тоже приходит число, но появляется оно не сразу, а с анимацией.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, способ подходящий. Только не получается сделать тоже самое со StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Если выставить FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop, то текст не обновляется на время анимации, а если выставить, то не сбрасывается к нужному после первого срабатывания

Comment: @Mihail: Хм, анимация строки и правда штука не очень понятная. Но зато получится анимировать цвет. А как именно должно меняться содержимое строки? Можно пример? (И если вы приведёте ваш код, я попробую оттестировать и починить.)

Comment: @VladD, текст отображает некоторое состояние системы (контроль включен или выключен) рядом с текстом переключатель. При смене его состояния из false в true текст сразу меняется на "подождите, идет обновление" и слегка плавно становится зеленым. Через пару секунд, текст меняется на тот, который загрузился, зеленый сбрасывается. Причем цвет после загрузки может оставаться серым, либо стать красным

Comment: @Mihail: А если как-то так: https://pastebin.com/dvxbyyEU?

Comment: @VladD, попробую. У меня сейчас проблема в том, что я не могу обновить свойство Foreground после анимации. Оно перестает реагировать на изменение в VM.  Когда анимация заканчивается мне нужно знать актуальное значение в VM, а цвет сбрасывается в то значение из которого он был анимирован, а не в то которое в VM

Comment: @Mihail: Там у анимации было свойство, которое регулирует, что происходит по окончанию анимации, может мы забыли его установить